# How can I send a Telegram message using curl from my own Telegram account (not from a bot)

Tags: telegram

I want to send a message to a group from Telegram user. The message should send from my personal account instead of the bot.

Is it possible, and if so what is the API method? I want to use CURL.

Vesa

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via HTTP request, if you want to send messages from a human account, try **unofficial** [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) instead.